# How to limit index column width/height when displaying a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(0,10)),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[str(list(range(0,1000)))],list(range(0,10))],
                                                   names=["ind1","ind2"]),
                  columns=["col1"])
df['col2']=str(list(range(0,1000)))
```

Unfortunately, the display of the above dataframe looks like this:

[image]

If I try to set: `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 5`, then `col2` behaves and it is displayed in a single row, but `ind1` doesn't behave:

[image]

Since `ind1` is part of a multiindex, I don't care it occupies multiple rows, but I would like to limit itself in width. If I could prescribe for each row to also occupy at most the height of a single line, that would be great as well. I don't care that individual cells are being truncated on display, because I prefer to have to scroll less, in any direction, to see a cell.

I am aware I can create my own HTML display. That's great and all, but I think it's too complex for my use case of just wanting smaller width columns for data analysis in jupyter notebooks. Nevertheless, such a solution might help other similar use cases, if you are inclined to write one.

What I'm looking for is some setting, which I thought it's `pd.options.display.max_colwidth`, that limits the column width, even if it's an index. Something that would disable wrapping for long texts would probably help with the same issue as well.

I also tried to just print without the index `df.style.hide_index()`, in combination with  `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 5`, but then `col2` stops behaving:

[image]

About now I run out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=list(range(0, 10)),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [[str(list(range(0, 1000)))], list(range(0, 10))], names=["ind1", "ind2"]
    ),
    columns=["col1"],
)
df["col2"] = str(list(range(0, 1000)))
```

In the next Jupyter cell, run:

```py
df.style.set_properties(**{"width": "10"}).set_table_styles(
    [{"selector": "th", "props": [("vertical-align", "top")]}]
)
```

Which outputs:

[image]